# JavaScript: String.search() can't search "[]" or "()"

Tags: javascript

If you try searching strings such as "`[]`" or "`()`" using the `search()` function it doesn't work.

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Visit []W3Schools!"; 
    var n = str.search("[]");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

You can try on W3Schools at - 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_search

Searching `[]` returns `-1`, while searching `()` returns `0`. Always.

Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[String.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) uses a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), and converts its argument to one if it isn't already. `[]` and `()` are special characters to RegExp.

You can directly create a regexp and escape the characters like so:

```
var n = str.search(/\[\]/);
```

But if you're searching for a literal string, then you should be using [String.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead.

```
var n = str.indexOf("[]");
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because search is expecting a regular expression. If a string is passed, then [**`search`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) will explicitly transform it into a regexp using `new RegExp`.

Calling it like `str.search("[]")` is like calling it  `str.search(/[]/)` (nothing in the string matches an empty set so `-1` is returned).

And calling it like `str.search("()")` is like calling it `str.search(/()/)` (the first empty string `""` is found at the index `0`).

I recommend looking for the docs on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) not W3Schools.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript search function takes a regular expression as its argument:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

In regular expressions, "[" and "(" are special characters.

Try replacing your function with this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Visit []W3Schools!"; 
    var n = str.search("\\[]");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

or better:

```
var n = str.search(/\[]/);
```

The '[' special character is escaped.  Once that is escaped, the ']' does not need to be escaped because it is only treated special after an unescaped '['.

For more information about regular expressions in JavaScript, look here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0):

Because the search string is a [regular-expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and "[]" and "()" are both magic.  You need to double-escape them:

```
str.search("\\[\\]")
```

Or even better, as ephemient points out:

```
str.indexOf("[]")
```